Sort days of the week extracted using TO_CHAR(order_date, 'Day') in PostgreSQL or Superset
I am working on Superset where I have extracted the day of the week from a DATE column (order_date) using the following SQL function:
TO_CHAR(order_date, 'Day') AS day_of_week

This gives me a string representation of the day, such as "Monday", "Tuesday", etc. When visualizing this data in Apache Superset, I am encountering a problem: the days appear in alphabetical order (e.g., Friday, Monday, Saturday...) instead of chronological order (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, ...).
What I Have Tried:
Extracting Numeric Day Values: I used the EXTRACT(DOW FROM order_date) function to extract the numeric representation of the day (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, ..., 6 = Saturday):
EXTRACT(DOW FROM order_date) AS day_of_week_num

Issue:
Superset only allows sorting based on the field actually added to the X-Axis and not another calculated field such as "day_of_week_num"
My goal:
I want the days of the week to appear in chronological order (Monday, Tuesday, ..., Sunday) in my visualizations while displaying the full day name (e.g., "Monday") on the X-axis.

Can you add order_date to the X-Axis, and format it like: TO_CHAR(order_date, 'Day') (and still order by order_date) ??

When adding order_date directly to the X-Axis, it asks for the time grain. I used the time grain as "Day" (because Day of the Week is not available there). When using TO_CHAR(order_Date, "Day") for the custom format, the following error appears:
DB engine Error
Unable to parse datetime string: Monday   , at position 0

There's even an issue about this, see: https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/13040  (Which got closed...)
